# How to show CamelCase names as hyphened or underscored names?

Tags: display

I have some complicated code with variables that use CamelCase.  Would it be possible to display such variables with a `hyphen (-)` or `underscore (_)`, but without modifying the actual text in the buffer.  Change would be just for display.

Comment: One way is to put what you want on the text using text property `display`. See [Replacing Specs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Replacing-Specs.html).

Comment: What would I have to do?

Comment: How would I code that?

Comment: @Drew Indeed, but someone already did it and packaged it in the last century, so no need to reinvent that wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what Glasses mode (`M-x glasses-mode`) does. See [MixedCase words](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/MixedCase-Words.html) and the `glasses` package documentation (`C-h p glasses RET`).

Use `M-x customize-group RET glasses RET` to see the available customizations. Glasses mode uses `_` as the sub-word separator by default, but you can use `-` or another character instead, or use no character but display the mid-word capital letter in a different color. Glasses mode can also convert from `snake_case` to `camelCase` on input, if what you're editing never uses snake case.

Comment: It works well for me.  I would like to change the separator mark from my init file using elisp code.  How should the change be?

Comment: A problem I have with it is this.  It is difficult to distinguish which words get changed.  For instance, if one has a mixture of `CamelCase`, `Under_scores` one would not know which is modified and which is original.  Particularly problematic when one is modifying the code.

Comment: @konmi Use the customize interface to change the settings. Change the “Glasses Face” to make the capital letter in a different color of font.

Comment: How can I do with elisp for my init file?

Comment: Another way I want to try is changing the background colour.